# What port should I use for file writing to file on a server? using Socket

Tags: java

Using a Socket to establish connection to my school linux server account. Main idea, connect to server and write text from desktop to an existing file on the server. 

I only can find Java doc examples of how to send data from server to desktop, I'm not sure if they are the same for both.

Don't know enough about computer networking, so Im unsure

1 what values to pass to the constructor Socket(String host, int port) 

Would the host name be `host = "myaccount@myserver.com"` or `host = "myserver.com"` ?

2 what port should I use to stream string/text data to the file on the server?

Comment: 1. Are you asking about the client side or the server side?  These will be different. 2. Unless you're intending to use a standard protocol, you can pick any one that your server isn't using.

Comment: how can I figure out what port my server is using? yes I need to know the port I should specific for the desktop side code. The desktop java will be making some data then sending it to the server via socket and using the server text/plain file.

Comment: If you coded the server, you will have coded in which port it should use.

Comment: got it. Have not written the java program on the server yet. Regarding this type of programming is it typically better to do server side first?

Answer (score 1):

it's a simple java file transfer

**Server**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(12345);
    File myFile = new File("freeman.txt");
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
      bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("freeman.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

As you can see instead of `127.0.0.1(localhost)` you can write your server, like `myserver.com` and instead of port, you can add your port

Comment: why does the client side use hostname "local" ? this doesn't make sense to me if you are connecting to the server why would you specify the name as local. You are also using the same port number for both sockets constructors which the guy above said not to do.

***EDIT: sorry I didn't see your message below the code.***

Comment: @localplutonium, Thanks for your reply, for testing I done that in same system because of that I wrote localhost, in socket programming we have to use same socket

Comment: lol okay I definitely understand that they cant be run on the same computer.

Comment: I rewrite it for you again, in simple method check this out.

Comment: got it so value don't have to be .. `hostname = "myaccount@server.com"` I just make it `hostname = "server.com"`... this was mainly my question I think I knew how to implement the rest.